# $L_p$ space and convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $f_i\rightarrow f$ $m$-a.e on $[0,1]$, $m$ is a measure and $\int|f_i(x)|^4dm$$\le1$ for all $i$.Then $\int|f_i(x)|^2dm\rightarrow \int|f(x)|^2dm$. how to prove it?

in my solution i prove that $|f_i(x)|^2\in L_2$ for all $i$ and $|f(x)|^2\in L_2$.
then use some statement (attached picture) where $r = 1,p = 2,F_i(x) =|f_i(x)|^2,F(x) =|f(x)|^2,C = 1$ and $f_n(x)\Rightarrow f(x)$ mean convergence in measure, but when measure is finite from a.e.convergence $\Rightarrow$ convergence in measure. It's right solution?[image]

Comment: is $m$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: yes, i think so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the quoted theorem.

We can also argue only with the dominated convergence theorem. Indeed, for a fixed $R$, we have 
$$\left|\int f_i^2-\int f^2\right|\leqslant \left|\int f_i^2\mathbf 1\{|f_i|\leqslant R\}-\int f^2\mathbf 1\{|f|\leqslant R\}\right|\\
+\left|\int f_i^2\mathbf 1\{|f_i|\gt R\}-\int f^2\mathbf 1\{|f|\gt R\}\right|\\
\leqslant \left|\int f_i^2\mathbf 1\{|f_i|\leqslant R\}-\int f^2\mathbf 1\{|f|\leqslant R\}\right|+\frac 2{R^2},$$
where we used $$\int f_i^2\mathbf 1\{|f_i|\gt R\}\leqslant \frac 1{R^2}\int f_i^4\leqslant \frac 1{R^2}$$
and the same inequality holds for $f$ by Fatou's lemma. 
By dominated  convergence, we have for each $R$ such that 
$m\{x\mid \left|f(x)\right|=R\}=0$, 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int f_i^2\mathbf 1\{|f_i|\leqslant R\}-\int f^2\mathbf 1\{|f|\leqslant R\}=0.$$
This is due to the fact that $\mathbf 1\{|f_i|\leqslant R\}\to\mathbf 1\{|f|\leqslant R\}$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Elegant trick, thanks!

Comment: but why function sequence $f_i^2 \{|f_i| \leq R\}$  converges pointwise to  $f^2 \{|f| \leq R\}$?
Did I understand correctly that you for each $|f_i|^2$ do own partition?

Comment: @Ialk Indeed, I had to be more careful. I have edited.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a simple application of Dominated Convergence Theorem. From assumption, we have that $|f_i|^2\longrightarrow |f|^2$ a.e on $[0,1]$. But 
\begin{equation*}
\int|f_i|^2\, dm\le \left(\int|f_i|^4\, dm\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le 1
\end{equation*}
where the first inequality follows from Holder inequality. Thus, DCT implies that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{i\to\infty} \int |f_i|^2\, dm = \int \lim_{i\to\infty} |f_i|^2\, dm = \int |f|^2\, dm
\end{equation*}

Comment: i think you wrong because in  Dominated Convergence Theorem "suppose that the sequence converges pointwise to a function f and is dominated by some integrable function g in the sense that $|f_i(x)| \le g(x)$" but we dont  know that $|f_i(x)| \le g(x)$ we know that  $\int|f_i(x)|^4dm \le 1$

Comment: It can be relaxed to a.e. convergence if we have a complete measure space, which is fine since you are working with Lebesgue measure. As for the second point, we are interested in showing $\int |f_i|^2$ converges, not $\int |f_i|$; that is the reason why I bound $|f_i|^2$ instead.

Comment: Okay, if we want to use DCT for $|f_i|^2$, we must have a function $g$, such that $|f_i(x)|^2 \leqslant g(x) \forall\, i$, and I don't understand what $g$ you use

Comment: The simplest bound is the function itself, i.e. $|f_i|^2\le |f_i|^2$ for all $i$. In practice, we have an explicit form for $f_i$ so we try to bound it by some function $g$ which we know belongs to $L^1$.

Comment: we need to construct one function $g$ , that would be greater than any $f_i$

Comment: Look at your first comment, it's greater or equal to.

Comment: yes, greater or equal to, but you supply each $f_i$ with its own function $g_i$, but we need one function $g$ for all $f_i$

Comment: Ahhh.................... we need a uniform bound.